# Paperclip error - NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError using amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, mongoid, paperclip

I've had Rails installed with Paperclip working just fine for a while until today. I don't know what cause this. I tried to learn about ImageMagick so I download it from the official website. After installed it I got an error about `libpng15.15.dylib` or something like that. So, I remove ImageMagick using `rm -rf` command from CLI. Then I installed it again using `homebrew`.

After that I ran my app again and got this error.

```
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/...-3gfyiu.png[0]' 2>/dev/null 
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
```

When I ran `identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/5x/...3gfyiu.png[0]` I got this error.

```
identify: unable to open image '/var/folders/....': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705.
identify: unable to open file '/var/folders/....' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3921.
```

and `identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/5x/...3gfyiu.png` I got this error.

```
 unknown image property "%[exif:orientation]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3762.
```

I know there are numerous Stackoverflow questions related to this, but all of those accepted answers didn't work for me.

These are what I've done so far.

- `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/identify"`
- `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"`
- `brew update && brew upgrade imagemagick`
- uninstall and install imagemagick
- downgrade `cocaine` to `0.3.2`
- `brew uninstall imagemagick jpeg libtiff
  brew install imagemagick`
- `brew install imagemagick --build-from-source`

The `identify` or `convert` commands work fine from CLI.

Environment:

- mongoid-paperclip 0.0.10
- paperclip 4.3.2
- mini_magick 4.5.1
- Rails 4.2.4
- Mac OS X Yosemite

Comment: Absolutelty the same problem today after brew upgrade imagemagick.

Somehow `identify -format '%wx%h,1' 'some_pic.jpg'` command works
and `identify -format '%wx%h,1' 'some_pic.jpg[0]'` isn't

Comment: @aristofun so how do you solve this?

Comment: Seems to be an imagemagick 6.9.4-7 bug
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646471/imagemagick-brackets-in-file-names-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x/37647282?noredirect=1#comment62775533_37647282

Comment: @aristofun so, does it work?

Comment: @aristofun thanks!! it's worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually installing `imagemagick-6.9.3-10` seems to fix the problem. So I believe it's a bug in imagemagick.

See [imagemagick: brackets in file names 'No such file or directory' — Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646471/imagemagick-brackets-in-file-names-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x#answer-37647282)