# imagemagick: brackets in file names 'No such file or directory' — Mac OS X

Tags: macos, imagemagick, homebrew

I've upgraded my Homebrew ImageMagick to `6.9.4-7` version (Mac OS 10.11.5), after which it doesn't understand brackets in file names anymore.

This command should consider the first frame of a picture:

```
identify -format '%wx%h,1' 'some_pic.jpg[0]'
```

For JPG it is actually just the picture, so the command is equivalent to:

```
identify -format '%wx%h,1' 'some_pic.jpg'
```

The *bracket* command works fine on my Ubuntu server and worked before on my Mac. But now it fails with

```
identify: unable to open image `some_pic.jpg[0]': 
No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2705.
```

Btw, this is the reason behind `Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError` on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Manually installing `imagemagick-6.9.3-10` via brew has fixed the problem. So I believe it's a bug in imagemagick.

**PS**:
To install specific version via brew, run

```
brew edit imagemagick
```

And edit these lines:

```
url "https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/imagemagick-6.9.4-7.tar.xz"
mirror "https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.9.4-7.tar.xz"
sha256 "f54fc8dcdb328404d1f89ddebe75d603e22894d3786ca2f2a9677478135b4c86"
```

May not work if the version you choose (https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew/mirror/) is not compatible with the rest of the brew formula. Then you need to go deeper.

Comment: The ImageMagick developers are aware of this bug. Expect a fix in ImageMagick-6.9.4-8 shortly.

Comment: Thank you! Aren't there tests for such a trivial case? :)

Comment: It does seem to be a bug. Can you please provide the instructions for installing imagemagick-6.9.3-10 via brew?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quote from 'some_pic.jpg' and then try to execute the command. It should run fine.